# Spawn a websocket client supposed to run continuously in a background service or keep it initialized by a SignalR hub?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, signalr-hub, background-service

I'm trying Blazor Server + SignalR streaming. Take a look at the following example. `WebSocketService` is a websocket client which is registered as a singleton. The received messages from that websocket client are pushed to the SignalR stream.

The question is do I have to initialize the websocket client in a separate `IHostedService`/`BackgroundService` like I usually do?

It works the way it is right now because it's a singleton. What are the best practices? I believe it's more appropriate to call it in a background service as the websocket client needs to run continuously in the background. This way, it can continue running and performing tasks even if the Hub is not in use.

Please keep in mind I made it that way, so I have the flexibility to send messages whenever I want, just by DI'ing it.

```cs
public sealed class WebSocketStreamHub : Hub
{
    private readonly WebSocketService _wsService;

    public WebSocketStreamHub(WebSocketService wsService)
    {
        _wsService = wsService;
    }

    public ChannelReader<string> GetChannelStream(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return _wsService.ChatObservable.AsChannelReader();
    }
}

public sealed class WebSocketService : IDisposable
{
    private readonly IWebsocketClient _ws;

    public WebSocketService()
    {
        _ws = new WebsocketClient(uri);

        _ws.ReconnectTimeout = null;
        _ws.ErrorReconnectTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15);

        _ws.ReconnectionHappened.Subscribe(info =>
            _logger.LogInformation("Reconnection happened, type: {Type}", info.Type));

        _ws.DisconnectionHappened.Subscribe(info =>
            _logger.LogInformation("Disconnection happened, type: {Type}", info.Type));

        _ = _ws.Start();
    }

    public IObservable<ChatMessage> ChatObservable => _ws.MessageReceived;

    public void Send(string message)
    {
        _ws.Send(message);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _ws.Dispose();
    }
}
```

```
@page "/"
@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client
@using Blazor.Data
@implements IAsyncDisposable

<div class="sticky-top w-50 mb-3 mt-3">
    <form @onsubmit="@(async () => await Send())">
        <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
            <select @bind="@_room" class="form-select">
                <option value="Trade">Trade</option>
                <option value="New Players">New Players</option>
            </select>

            <input @bind="@_message" type="text" class="form-control w-auto">

            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" disabled="@(!IsConnected)">Send</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>

<pre>
    @foreach (var message in _messages)
    {
        <div class="text-secondary">[@message.RoomId] @message.SenderName says: @message.MessageText</div>
    }
</pre>

@code
{
    private readonly Queue<ChatMessage> _messages = new();

    private HubConnection? _hubConnection;
    private CancellationTokenSource? _channelCancellationTokenSource;

    private string _room = "Trade";
    private string _message = "";

    private async Task GetChannelStream()
    {
        if (_hubConnection is null)
        {
            return;
        }

        _channelCancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

        var channel = await _hubConnection.StreamAsChannelAsync<ChatMessage>("GetChannelStream",
            _channelCancellationTokenSource.Token);

        while (await channel.WaitToReadAsync())
        {
            while (channel.TryRead(out var message))
            {
                if (_messages.Count >= 20)
                {
                    _messages.Dequeue();
                }

                _messages.Enqueue(message);

                await InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
            }
        }

        _channelCancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
    }

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        _hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
            .WithUrl(NavigationManager.ToAbsoluteUri("/chathub"))
            .Build();

        await _hubConnection.StartAsync();

        _ = GetChannelStream();;
    }

    private async Task Send()
    {
        if (_hubConnection is not null)
        {
            await _hubConnection.SendAsync("SendMessage", _room, _message);

            _message = "";
        }
    }

    public bool IsConnected => _hubConnection?.State == HubConnectionState.Connected;

    public async ValueTask DisposeAsync()
    {
        if (_hubConnection is not null)
        {
            await _hubConnection.DisposeAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the interaction model you are looking for? How does the client call this API? How does this API? Is this API just for sending data or receiving data

Comment: @davidfowl, it's a chat. The websocket client (`WebSocketService`) connects to a 3rd party websocket server and essentially is responsible for sending/receiving data and streaming that data to the SignalR Hub.

Comment: @davidfowl, I added some code. That's what it does.

Comment: I noticed `it can continue running and performing tasks even if the Hub is not in use` and I'm not sure about your requirement. Could you pls describe it? For me since this is a chat, the client should have `on-disconnect` event and can we do some logic in that event?

Comment: @TinyWang, I mean the websocket client should be running either way.

Comment: sorry that I still can't understand..... sorry for it..